# Is it possible to make more font styles available to the Preview App?

Tags: preview, font

I need to use the Gill Sans Light font, but Preview can only see the standard Gill Sans.

Is there anyway at all to force the Preview app to see more options for this particular font?

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: You my want to be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, with examples. If you add a font to the system all applications have access to it. It may be that the Gill Sans Light you have is not the same Gill Sans Light that the (presumed) document specifies.